# Parabolas - Which values of $x$ will make it negative?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have always seen a question about parabolas asking: for which values of $x$ is the given function negative.
$$y= x^2-6x+5$$
What does that mean?

Comment: Parabola, parabola, parabola

Answer (score 2):

What it is asking you is, "What values of $x$ will make $y$ less than $0$?" All you need to do is to solve the inequality $x^2-6x+5<0$.
$$x^2-6x+5<0$$
$$(x-1)(x-5)<0$$
The roots of this function are $1$ and $5$. The values of $x$ less than $0$ will be between these two roots (not including them). Therefore:
$$1<x<5$$
So, any value of $x$ between $1$ and $5$, not including the two numbers, will make $y$ less than $0$, in other words, negative.

---

Here is what the function looks like when graphed:

[image: Graph of the function]

As you can see, the values of $x$ that make the curve negative, or go below $0$, are between $1$ and $5$. This is written as $1<x<5$.

I hope I helped you.

Comment: don't you mean $x^2-6x+5 <0$?

Comment: WOOPS!!! Thx for pointing that out

Answer (score 0):

A function is negative for those values of x for which the graph of the function is below the y-axis.
$$y<0$$
$$x^2 - 6x + 5 < 0$$
$$(x-5)(x-1)<0$$
$$\implies 1<x<5$$
So for $1<x<5$, the function will be negative.